# Angular 2 + CORS + Spring Boot Rest Controller with Spring Security

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc, spring-security, cors

I am using angular2 for front end and spring boot rest controller. Before adding spring security my application worked fine. After adding security the function with parameters are not invoked in the spring boot rest controller.Below is the code

```
Rest Controller:
----------------
@RestController
public class JobCleanupServiceController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobCleanupServiceController.class);
   @Autowired
   JobCleanupDAO dao;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @RequestMapping("/jobcleanup")

    public Collection<JobCleanup> index(@RequestBody String owner) {

        logger.info("Display All Jobs"+ owner);
        return dao.findAll(owner);

    }


    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @RequestMapping("/jobcleanupclosedtickets")

    public JobCleanupMetrics getJobCleanupClosedTickets()
    {
        logger.info("JobCleanupMetrics getJobCleanupClosedTickets ");
        return dao.getJobCleanupClosedTickets();
    }



    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @RequestMapping("/jobcleanuplinechartdata")
    public JobCleanupChart getJobCleanupLineChartData(@RequestBody String  owner){
        return dao.getJobCleanupLineChartData(owner);
    }

WebConfig.java
-------------

@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

### SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/jobcleanup",
                            "/jobcleanupclosedtickets",
                            "/jobcleanuplinechartdata"
                    ).permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Before i added spring security when i enter http://localhost:4200 , all these were called  "/jobcleanup",
  "/jobcleanupclosedtickets",
 "/jobcleanuplinechartdata". After adding spring security only "/jobcleanupclosedtickets" is called other methods are not getting called.
except "/jobcleanupclosedtickets" other methods have request body.

Can someone please help me to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Updated the SecurityConfig.java as below works. By default csrf is enabled in spring security.

```
 @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.cors();

        }

        @Bean
        public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
            configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
            configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
            final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
            return source;
        }
    }
```