# Spring Boot JWT CORS with Angular 6

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors, jwt

I am using JWT in my Spring Boot app. When I try to login from the Angular 6 client, I get the CORS error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8082/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I tried adding headers for `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, I even tried using some chrome extensions and still it couldn't bypass the CORS. I can access the login API with Postman and get the token.

Spring Boot Classes

`WebSecurityConfig.java`

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurityConfig(@Qualifier("customUserDetailsService") UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

        @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                    .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
```

`WebConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry) {
        corsRegistry.addMapping( "/**" )
                .allowedOrigins( "http://localhost:4200" )
                .allowedMethods( "GET", "POST", "DELETE" )
                .allowedHeaders( "*" )
                .allowCredentials( true )
                .exposedHeaders( "Authorization" )
                .maxAge( 3600 );
    }

}
```

`JWTAuthorization.java` the class that gives access to user

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(authenticationManager);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }


        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = getAuthenticationToken(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);



        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }



    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthenticationToken(HttpServletRequest request){
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();
            System.out.println(user);
            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

`JWTAuthenticationFilter.java` the class that handles the login request and returns the token

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(),User.class);
            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            user.getUsername(),
                            user.getPassword())
                    );

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String username = ((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
        String token = Jwts
                .builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET)
                .compact();

        System.out.println("TOKEN: " + token);

        String bearerToken = TOKEN_PREFIX + token;
        response.getWriter().write(bearerToken);
        response.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, bearerToken);

    }
}
```

Postman example that works

[image]

Here is how I make the post request to login that gives me the error

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  public apiURL:string="http://localhost:8082";

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  validateUser(user:User){

    let userData = "username=love"+ "&password=12345" + "&grant_type=password";
    let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("username", user.username);
    data.append("password", user.password);

    console.log(data);


    return this.httpClient.post<User>(this.apiURL + '/login',data,{headers:reqHeader});
  }

  storeToken(token: string) {
    localStorage.setItem("token", token);
  }
  getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem("token");
  }
  removeToken() {
    return localStorage.removeItem("token");
  }
}
```

Also the `User` interface in Angular

```
export interface User {
  username:string;
  password:string;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since message is about your **preflight** request i.e. `OPTIONS` request,

I guess, you need to do two things on server side / Spring Boot code ,

1. Return OK from Authentication filter so need to add below in `attemptAuthentication` method as first check i.e. don't do real authentication for preflight requests,

`if (CorsUtils.isPreFlightRequest(httpServletRequest)) {
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        return new Authentication() ; //whatever your token implementation class is - return an instance of it

    }`

CorsUtils is - `org.springframework.web.cors.CorsUtils`

2. Let Spring Security Enter Authorized Options requests into System so add these lines in Security Config ,

`.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()`

You can allow unauthorized OPTIONS requests too but I guess , that wouldn't be a good idea. Also, try to narrow down "/**" to specific URLs if possible.

Comment: I am not sure where to place the first statement, you said below the `attemptAuthentication`. Did you mean inside or before try-catch?

Comment: as first thing in that method, either inside `try` as first thing or before `try` as long as its first thing that you do.

Comment: It wasn't exactly the answers your provided, but  it gave me an idea based on another question, link for anyone interested in the future https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410682/angular-2-cors-spring-boot-rest-controller-with-spring-security/46410953#46410953

Comment: I mean , this set up works for me with Angular5  & also ..I have the set up what other answer is saying but when I looked at your question , I thought you already have that portion. Anyway, issue is resolved, that is good to know.

Comment: is there a other way than permitAll HttpMethod.OPTIONS? It looks to me like a security thread.

Comment: There is another good solution [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cors-preflight) (already posted below) for solving Spring CORS issue. Add `http.cors();` to your Security config.

Answer (score 5):

**1) Create a bean returning `CorsFilter`**

I did it in `SecurityConfig` class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //.... 
        http.cors();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

**2) Provide this `CorsFilter` to the class extending `SecurityConfigurerAdapter`**

```java
public class JwtConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {
    private final JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider; 

    public JwtConfigurer(JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider) {
        this.jwtTokenProvider = jwtTokenProvider;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter = new JwtTokenFilter(jwtTokenProvider);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(
                new SecurityConfig(jwtTokenProvider).corsFilter(), 
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(
                jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

**3) Add in method `configure(HttpSecurity http) { /* ... */ http.cors(); }` in `SecurityConfig` class**

Shown in the first code snippet above.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem, finally i only added `httpRequest.cors();` at the end of configure method in the  WebSecurityConfig class and it worked well, **the explanation of why is**  :

explicitly  the preflight requests are not excluded from authorization in  Spring Security configuration. Remember that Spring Security secures all endpoints by default.

As a result,  API expects an authorization token in the OPTIONS request as well.

Spring provides an out of the box solution to exclude OPTIONS requests from authorization checks:

The `cors()`method will add the Spring-provided CorsFilter to the application context which in turn bypasses the authorization checks for OPTIONS requests.

**for all details** 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cors-preflight

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue.When i tried from postman it worked fine but same call made from react app i faced issue.

Generally we disable cors in configuration while working with the spring security.
But here you should allow it. Check the below code snippet.

Just added  **http.cors();** in below code

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

        
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
            }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
 http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/secure/authenticate")
        .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);;
        http.cors();
                
    }

    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and the problem was the name of the packages... Try to rename your packages in this model: groupId.artifactId.security.jwt