# cros error for auth api calls using spring security

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have setup the cros as below for spring boot application with spring security. 
Spring-boot application with spring security along with jwt token.

I am consuming the api's with other domain so i am using cross origin on all the controllers.

All the api calls which are not required auth token(JWT) are working perfectly fine with below configurations. But the api calls with which required jwt token are failing with below error.

I am trying to add filters but its not working as expected. can some one help me here.

thanks.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;

    private final DomainUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;

//    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;
    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder, DomainUserDetailsService userDetailsService, TokenProvider tokenProvider, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
        this.authenticationManagerBuilder = authenticationManagerBuilder;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
//        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
    }

        @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().disable().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/api/**", "/reports/**", "/utils/**").and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/*.html", "/**/*.js", "/**/*.png", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.woff2", "/**/*.woff",
                        "/**/*.ico", "/**/*.ttf", "/**/*.jpg")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/api/auth/**", "/api/util/**", "/api/feed/getJobs", // feed can be seen
                                                                                                // without auth
                        "/api/user/user-details/**", // user details can be seen without auth
                        "/v2/api-docs/**", "/actuators/**", "/api-docs/**", "/utils/**")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().apply(securityConfigurerAdapter()).and()
                // handle an authorized attempts
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint((req, rsp, e) -> rsp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED));
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider, userDetailsService);
    }
```

GET, POST, PUT, DELETE api calls with out jwt is working.

**API calls with JWT is not working getting below error**

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8082/api/feed/posted-by-me' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

can some one tell what i am doing wrong??

i am using Angular 9 at front-end to call the apis.

Comment: Remove `cors().disable()` in `configure(HttpSecurity http)` and try again

Comment: @PatelRomil, tried but no luck. still same error  `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8082/api/feed/posted-by-me' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`.

Comment: Do you have any configuration related to CORS in other classes such as at controller level or in yml or properties files?

Comment: @PatelRomil, I have kept `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)` at controller. Apart from that i dont have any configurations.

Comment: Can you please remove `@CrossOrigin` from controller and try again

Comment: Tied but still the same error

Comment: It should work. You may share the repository if possible

Comment: send you request in linkedIn, will share you my skype ID. i can demo the issue.

Comment: this is worked for me :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605255/spring-boot-jwt-cors-with-angular-6/62250980#62250980

Answer (score 0):

the issue was the filter which i was using on the above class was not working. so i created new filter class like below then it started working as exected.

```
package com.happyconnects.web.api.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, Authorization, Cache-control, remember-me");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```