# in spring boot 2.3.3, facing issue regarding CORS. no spring security has been used

Tags: spring-boot, csrf

"has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

getting this message when api is being hit by angular portion, but proper response is obtained when end point is being hit from POSTMAN.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot JWT CORS with Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605255/spring-boot-jwt-cors-with-angular-6)

Answer (score -1):

You will need to enable/configure [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) in your spring boot application -

Enabling CORS for the whole application (This is a global configuration)-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

Additionally Spring allows you to control CORS configuration at Controller as well as at the RequestMapping level -

To enable CORS for the whole controller -

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://your-client-domain.com", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/booking")
public class BookingController {

    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public Booking retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, path = "/{id}")
    public void remove(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To enable the CORS for specific path mapping (RequestMapping) -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/booking")
public class BookingController {

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://your-client-domain.com")
    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public Booking retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, path = "/{id}")
    public void remove(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can also apply CORS configuration only for required mappings (paths), you can always configure it to the granular details -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/v1/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://your-client-domain.com")
            .allowedMethods("OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("Some-Header-x", "Authorization")
            .exposedHeaders("X-API-Limit")
            .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

You can read more about enabling and configuring CORS in Spring Applications [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

Comment: none of this worked when api is being hit from angular portion

Comment: Since preflight is associated with OPTIONS method, you should enable/allow it, check last part of the answer. Also adding some code about your Security Configuration will help a lot.

Comment: I tried the last one, would you take a look in this?


2020-10-20 12:32:58 INFO Request Filtering: 
User-agent => Web, 
UserId => null, 
Token => null, 
UserIp => , 
requestUrl => http://:9090/seller/shop/category, Method type => OPTIONS
2020-10-20 12:32:58 INFO Request Filtering: Invalid User Id
2020-10-20 12:32:58 INFO Response: Invalid User Id

Comment: I'mm sending user id and token from header and getting null when this api is beng hit from angular. from postman, there's no issue

Comment: Can you post your security and web configuration?

Comment: `@Configuration
`@EnableWebMvc
`public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
`@Override
`public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
`registry.addMapping("/**")
`.allowedOrigins("**")
`.allowedMethods("OPTIONS", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
`.allowedHeaders("*")
`.exposedHeaders("**")
`.allowCredentials(true).maxAge(3600);
`}
`}

Comment: The thing is. I've added two self defined headers here, and I can't get them, UserId => null, Token => null

Comment: How are you accessing the custom headers?

Comment: through filters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223347/discussion-between-tanuj-and-subha-bhowmik).